# Unanticipated <xsl:apply-imports/> behavior

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I've been trying to figure out how to best modularize my XSLT stylesheets to facilitate re-use.  I hit upon the idea of using <xsl:apply-imports/> as a way of introducing document-specific attributes to standard tag transformations.  This is **not** working the way I expected it would, and I can't even begin to fathom what is going on here.  Here is a simplified version of the stylesheet:

```
<!-- main.xsl -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<xsl:import href="html-customizations.xsl"/>

<xsl:output method="xml"
   indent="yes"
   omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

<xsl:template match="para">
  <fo:block>
      <xsl:attribute name="space-after">1em</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<!-- =============== -->
<!-- Inline Elements -->
<!-- =============== -->

<xsl:template match="i">
  <fo:inline font-style="italic">
    <xsl:apply-imports/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ================ -->
<!--      Tables      -->
<!-- ================ -->

<xsl:template match="table">
  <fo:table>
    <xsl:apply-imports/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template  match="tr">
  <fo:table-row>
    <xsl:apply-imports/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td | th">
  <fo:table-cell>
    <xsl:apply-imports/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The imported stylesheet:

```
<!-- html-customizations.xsl -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<xsl:template  match="td | th">
  <xsl:attribute name="hyphenate">true</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the XML input file:

```
<!-- test.xml -->
<para>
  <table>
    <tr><td>Spongebob Squarepants, <i>Chair</i></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Patrick Starfish, <i>Vice Cchair</i></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Squidword, <i>Secretary</i></td></tr>
  </table>
</para>
```

$
    xalan -o out.xml test.xml main.xsl

```
out.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:block xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" space-after="1em">
  <fo:table>
    <fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell hyphenate="true">Spongebob Squarepants, <fo:inline font-style="italic">ChairChair</fo:inline>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell hyphenate="true">Spongebob Squarepants, <fo:inline font-style="italic">ChairChair</fo:inline>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell hyphenate="true">Patrick Starfish, <fo:inline font-style="italic">Vice CchairVice Cchair</fo:inline>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell hyphenate="true">Patrick Starfish, <fo:inline font-style="italic">Vice CchairVice Cchair</fo:inline>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell hyphenate="true">Squidword, <fo:inline font-style="italic">SecretarySecretary</fo:inline>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell hyphenate="true">Squidword, <fo:inline font-style="italic">SecretarySecretary</fo:inline>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell hyphenate="true">Spongebob Squarepants, <fo:inline font-style="italic">ChairChair</fo:inline>
...
...
```

As you can see, every child of an element matched by a template that includes <xsl:apply-imports/> is repeated!  I included the imported stylesheet in order to illustrate what I'm trying to do.  If I comment out this import:

```
<!--
<xsl:import href="html-customizations.xsl"/>
-->
```

The repeating behavior is the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:block xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" space-after="1em">
  <fo:table>
    <fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell>Spongebob Squarepants, <fo:inline font-style="italic">ChairChair</fo:inline>Spongebob Squarepants, <fo:inline font-style="italic">ChairChair</fo:inline>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell>Spongebob Squarepants, <fo:inline font-style="italic">ChairChair</fo:inline>Spongebob Squarepants, <fo:inline font-style="italic">ChairChair</fo:inline>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-row>
...
...
```

sans the attribute I'm trying to add from the imported stylesheet; i.e. just the **presence** of the <xsl:apply-imports/> processing instruction causes the output elements to be doubled.  Also note that this is not just a **xalan** problem -- the same thing happens on MSXML on Windows 7.

Any thoughts?  I was counting on this working, so am now pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to fix this so it works.

BTW, my assumptions of how <xsl:apply-imports/> can be used is based on the examples given under the **xsl:import** section of Michael Kay's book.  If anyone knows of a reference that explains the behavior I'm seeing above, please share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that the behaviour of `apply-imports` is difficult to understand. The problem is that `apply-imports` *always* finds a template that matches the current node, even if the user did not define it. In that case, the *default* template applies.

The following stylesheet works:

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:import href="html-customizations.xsl"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml"
        indent="yes"
        omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:attribute name="space-after">1em</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- =============== -->
    <!-- Inline Elements -->
    <!-- =============== -->

    <xsl:template match="i">
        <fo:inline font-style="italic">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:inline>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ================ -->
    <!--      Tables      -->
    <!-- ================ -->

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <fo:table>

            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template  match="tr">
        <fo:table-row>

            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td | th">
        <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:apply-imports/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, I have removed two `apply-imports` elements, only leaving the one inside `template/@match='td | th'`. Then, the output will be

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:block xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" space-after="1em">
    <fo:table>
        <fo:table-row>
         <fo:table-cell hyphenate="true">Spongebob Squarepants, <fo:inline font-style="italic">ChairChair</fo:inline>
         </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row>
         <fo:table-cell hyphenate="true">Patrick Starfish, <fo:inline font-style="italic">Vice CchairVice Cchair</fo:inline>
         </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row>
         <fo:table-cell hyphenate="true">Squidword, <fo:inline font-style="italic">SecretarySecretary</fo:inline>
         </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table>
</fo:block>
```

**What exactly is happening?**

`apply-imports` looks for a template that

- matches the current node
- matches the current mode
- is inside an imported stylesheet

Now, the crucial bit is: this instruction will invoke the [**built-in templates**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3378562/1987598) if no such template can be found in an imported stylesheet. In the case of `tr`:

```
<xsl:template  match="tr">
  <fo:table-row>
    <xsl:apply-imports/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
```

The default action for element nodes is traversing it and applying templates to its content, so the snippet above actually translates to

```
<xsl:template  match="tr">
  <fo:table-row>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
```

and this is why the output contains duplicates. I assume now you also understand why commenting out `xsl:import` did not help, otherwise I'm glad to elaborate.

---

Since you were also asking for a reference, this *is* explained in the *XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference* by Michael Kay, page 238.

Comment: Thanks, Mathias -- that answers my question.  In your example, you also need to take the <xsl:apply-templates> out of the `match="i"` template -- notice that the italicized text is still doubled; e.g. ChairChair.  Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem, as I want the main style sheet (actually the design is simplified for the question -- actually, there is in intermediate stylesheet) which I want to be able to use completely unedited.   If I have to edit this stylesheet, I might as well just put everthing into the templates there.

Comment: Meanwhile, I think I've thought of another way of doing this:  call generic attribute sets on each element that are defined in an included stylesheet and which might or might not have any content.  I will think about this a bit more and then post an example for the benefit of the next person who comes along with a question about this.  Thanks again!  I thought I was going insane trying to debug this yesterday, as the actual stylesheet is quite long and complicated.  It took me several hours before I realized that <xsl:apply-imports> was responsible for my misery.

Comment: @pgoetz You are right, edited my answer to remove the `apply-imports`. Wouldn't assigning attribute sets to elements not also require you to edit the main stylesheet?

Comment: No, I would include the attribute sets in a separate stylesheet and then call them generically:  `<fo:table-cell  xsl:use-attribute-sets="customize-td">`.  The attribute set `customize-td` is defined in a separated included stylesheet and will generally be empty (but can be used to set document-specific default attributes for the entire document).